# Why HashMap resize In case of collision or worst case

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

I am asking this question with respect to java version till 1.7 only. I am using reflection to find out current capacity of HashMap. In below program is putting 12 unique person into a single bucket of HashMap (using same hashcode). Then i am putting 13th unique person on same or different bucket(using same or different hashcodes). In both cases after adding this 13th element, HashMap resizes to 32 buckets. I understand that due to load factor .75 and initial capacity 16 HashMap resizes to its double with 13th element. But there are still empty buckets available and only 2 buckets are used for these 13th elements.

My questions are:

1. Is my understanding correct. Am I not making any mistake. Is this the expected behavior of HashMap?
2. If all this is correct then even though there are 12 or 11 free buckets why the need to double the HashMap with 13th element in this case. Isn't it extra overhead or costly to resize the HashMap? What is the need to double the HashMap in this case While 13th can be put in any available bucket according to hashcode?

.

```
public class HashMapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        HashMap<Person, String> hm = new HashMap<Person, String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            // 12 Entry in same bucket(linkedlist)
            hm.put(new Person(), "1");
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Buckets in HashMap : " + bucketCount(hm));
        System.out.println("Number of Entry in HashMap :  " + hm.size());
        System.out.println("**********************************");
        // 13th element in different bucket
        hm.put(new Person(2), "2");
        System.out.println("Number of Buckets in HashMap : " + bucketCount(hm));
        System.out.println("Number of Entry in HashMap :  " + hm.size());
    }

    public static int bucketCount(HashMap<Person, String> h)
            throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field tableField = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("table");
        tableField.setAccessible(true);
        Object[] table = (Object[]) tableField.get(h);
        return table == null ? 0 : table.length;
    }
}

class Person {
    int age = 0;

    Person() {
    }

    Person(int a) {
        age = a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (age != 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return age;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Number of Buckets in HashMap : 16
Number of Entry in HashMap :  12
**********************************
Number of Buckets in HashMap : 32
Number of Entry in HashMap :  13
```

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful For the 2nd answer, load factor works on Entry count. Why it don't see already available buckets. Why it do resize which hurts performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. yes, and this is the expected behavior.
2. The HashMap doesn't care about how many buckets are used. It only knows that the load factor has been reached, and that the probability of having collisions is thus becoming too big, and the map should thus be resized. Even though many collisions already happened, resizing the map could actually fix that. Not in your case, since you chose identical hashCode on purpose, but in a more realistic case, hashCodes should have a much better distribution. HashMap can't do anything to make itself efficient if you choose bad hashCodes on purpose, and there is no point in adding complexity to handle an extreme case, that should never happen, and that HashMap won't be able to fix anyway.

Comment: Hi JB ! I noticed 1 more thing. For 13th element capacity becomes 32 due to loadfactor .75. Now if i am removing elements 1 by 1 from the HashMap. capacity doesn't come back to 16. Even HashMap now containing 7 Entries only. Capacity is still 32. Is there no need to become less capacity for HashMap if entries count is going down?

Comment: No, HashMap expands as needed, but never shrinks back.

Comment: Oh Ok Thanks JB :)

Comment: @Pradeep if you want hashmap to shrinks back, you can always define custom implementation of hashmap by implementing Map interface.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the behavior you observe is the expected behavior.

The implementation of `HashMap` expects you to use a reasonable `hashCode` for the keys. It assumes that your `hashCode` would distribute the keys as evenly as possible among the available buckets. If you fail to do that (as you did in your example - where all the keys have the same `hashCode`), you will get bad performance.

Under the assumption of even distribution, it makes sense for the `HashMap` to double its size once you pass the load factor. It doesn't check how many buckets are actually empty (since it has no way of knowing if new entries will be assigned to empty buckets or to occupied buckets). It just checks the average number of entries per bucket. Once that number exceeds the load factor, the number of buckets is doubled.

Comment: Ean As per your answer you said that **since it has no way of knowing if new entries will be assigned to empty buckets or to occupied buckets** .    Now  Question 1 .    How particular bucket linked to a HashCode. I think First HasCode is calculated then this is attched/link to the empty bucket. Please correct me if i am wrong.      Question2.  what i think is a new entry will surely assigned to either empty bucket or to already occupied bucket.  Now in both cases doubling the size of hashmap doesn't need. Am i wrong?   Yes if all buckets are full then it make sense to double the HashMap

Comment: @PradeepSingh A hashCode is mapped to a bucket based on the value of the hashCode (which is transformed by the HashMap implementation to try to improve the distribution) and the current number of buckets. Whether the bucket is already occupied or not makes no difference.

Comment: @PradeepSingh As for you second question, doubling the HashMap helps when keys with different hash codes are mapped to the same bucket. When the map is doubled, such keys may be separated into different buckets, thus reducing search time in those buckets, since the new buckets will each have less entries than the original bucket.

Comment: Couldn't understand the line **when keys with different hash codes are mapped to the same bucket.**         How this happens? As per my knowledge different hash codes should mapped to the same bucket.

Comment: @PradeepSingh Try a `HashMap<Integer,String>`. The initial number of buckets is 16. If the first keys you put are 1 and 17, their corresponding hashCodes are also 1 and 17, and both will be mapped to bucket #1.

Comment: @PradeepSingh for the sake of simplicity, let's assume the bucket is chosen using hashCode % numberOfBuckets. Now suppose the number of buckets is 7 and the hashCodes are 0, 7, 14, 21 and 28. All the objects would end up in the same bucket 0. Now if the map is resized to 11 buckets, the objects end up respectively to bucket 0, 0, 3, 10, and 6.

Comment: I understand that resizing can help in more equally distribution. Thanks you so much guys. Now i want correct the answer. Both the answers are equally valuable and important. I personally feel the answer from JB correctly explaining the reason behind Resizing when collision occurs. Thanks Again :) :)

Answer (score 3):

There is one slight aspect here also; while you resize the internal array (goes from 16 to 32) you are also "touching" all the entries. let me explain:

when there are 16 buckets (internal array is of size 16), only the `last 4 bits` decide where that entry will go; think `%`, but internally its actually `(n - 1) & hash`, where `n` is the number of buckets.

When the internal array grows, one more bit is taken into consideration to decide where an entry goes: there used to be `4 bits`, now there are `5 bits`; that means that all the entries are *re-hashed* and they potentially might move to different buckets now; that is why the resizing happens, to disperse entries.

If you *really* want to fill all the "gaps", you specify a `load_factor` of `1`; instead of the default of `0.75`; but that has implications as documented in the HashMap constructors.